# java split string

Tags: java, regex, string, split, tokenize

in Java, if I have a string with this format:

```
( string1 , string2 ) ( string2 ) ( string4 , string5 , string6 ) [s2]
```

How can I split the string to get an array of string as this?

```
string1 , string2
string2
string4 , string5 , string6
```

Comment: Do you want a single array of strings or an array of arrays of strings?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
    String test = "( string1 , string2 ) ( string2 ) ( string4 , string5 , string6 ) [s2]";

    String[] splits = test.split("\\(\\s*|\\)[^\\(]*\\(?\\s*");

    for (String split : splits) {
        System.out.println(split);
    }
```

Comment: +1 `split()` is a little simpler in concept, but I would either add in a bit to match any whitespace before the closing parentheses as well as after the opening ones, or remove the whitespace matching all together.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a match :

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
}
```

Matches anything between () and stores it into backreference 1.

**Explanation :**

```
 "\\(" +      // Match the character “(” literally
"(" +       // Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   "." +       // Match any single character that is not a line break character
      "*?" +      // Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
")" +
"\\)"        // Match the character “)” literally
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use split on `/\(.+?\)/` - something like this in java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(.+?\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    ar.add(m.group());
}
String[] result = new String[ar.size()];
result = ar.toArray(result);
```